# Not Found Hangouts Chat API in Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-hangouts

Using the manual on the link https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/quickstart/apps-script-bot did not find the "Hangouts Chat API"

Comment: which step of the manual did you skip?

Comment: @ZF007 I stopped at step 2: Publish the bot (Search for "Hangouts Chat API" and enable the API)

Answer (score 0):

The Hangouts Chat API currently shows for me:

[image]

Maybe it was a temporary bug on the backend. Can you check if it works for you now?